# How to reduce space after label?

Tags: spacing, graphics, subcaption

I want to reduce the space between label and caption in subfigure.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{ABCDEFGHIJK}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hspace{6em}% Space between image A and B
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.19\linewidth}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABCDEFGHIJK}
  \end{subfigure}%
 \caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By adding option  `skip=....` at loading `subcation` package. For example: `\usepackage[skip=3pt]{subcaption}`

Comment: I tried to use '\subcaptionbox{ABCDEFGHIJK}[2.5cm]{\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b}}' as the same result.

Comment: The problem is, the captions should be set ragged right, but they are not.  Unfortunately, I don't have time at the moment to research how best to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}   % <---
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width = \linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{ABC DEF GHIJK}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.19\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABC DEFG HIJK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like this global setting, you can do it locally just for this figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width = \linewidth}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex}    % <---
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{ABC DEF GHIJK}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.19\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABC DEFG HIJK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For even smaller vertical distance, reduce `skip` size.

**Edit:**
It seems, as follows from your comment, that you like to have smaller space between caption label and its text. This can be achieved if you not required justified text in caption, i.e. that text in caption can be ragged at right side:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=RaggedRight]{subcaption}
```

or

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{subcaption}
```

In your particular caption text case at both you will get the same result (since text is not natural and consequently words hyphenation doesn't work properly):

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=RaggedRight]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width = \linewidth}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex}    % <---
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{ABC DEF GHIJK}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.19\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABC DEFG HIJK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** for keeping sub caption in one line make `subfigure` environment bigger. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}   % <---
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width = \linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{ABC DEF GHIJK}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABC DEFG HIJK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.66\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{ABC DEF GHIJK}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.66\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{ABC DEFG HIJK}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example images for the different group in Chest X-ray dataset.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried following your advice (method: locally just for this figure), but got the same result. For the caption, if I use 8 characters (Ex. ABC DEFG) the caption will be on the same line and no skip. But if I use characters > 8 (with space), the caption will have a skip and have two lines. I think the problem is **\hfil**. So, I replace **\hfil** by **\hspace{5em}**. But I got the same output. I'm not sure Where did I go wrong.

Comment: @Jaturong, sorry, but I not understand you, what is your problem problem. A I understood you, this is vertical distance between subcaptions and caption. On this the distance between images doesn't has any influence.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't describe the problem well. I mean that, I want to reduce the space between labels (A,B) and subcaption of  each figure (ABCDEFGHIJK). Is there a way to keep the subcaption on the same line? For example, (A) ABCDEFGHIJK

Comment: @Jaturong, your question is about caption formatting ... see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.